# How windows works both on Intel and Arm processors

Tags: arm, intel

I just started studying operating systems and something I realized recently is that how much of a difference is there between processor architectures and operating system implementations.

So, I was wondering if someone can tell me certain pointers on how did Microsoft got windows to work on both ARM and Intel. It would be great for my further reading and direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until recently, Windows was not compiled for ARM.  Windows CE, Windows Embedded Compact, Windows RT, Windows Phone, etc were all compiled for and executed on ARM; however, the Desktop and Server versions of Windows remained strictly on Intel architecture.  Beginning with Windows 10, there will be some convergence where all versions of the OS will share a common core which will be compiled on multiple architectures.

The majority of the OS is written in C/C++ for which compilers on these architectures are well developed.  The greater challenges are in maintaining or unifying the architecture specific implementations, optimizations and assembly code.  In many cases, separate architecture specific code will have to be maintained.

The Linux kernel is quite similar in this regard.  Different toolchains and compiler configurations are used to compile the kernel for different architectures.  Additionally, configuration parameters are used to enable and link in different code fragments at compile time.

Comment: For desktop/server (i.e. NT family) I guess "strictly on Intel architecture" is semi-true in the sense that it could stretch to x86, x86-64, IA-64 and the early i960 development, but what about Alpha, PowerPC and MIPS? :P

Comment: @Notlikethat good point, prior to Windows 2000, other architectures were supported by NT 4.0 and earlier.  Although for the last 15 years, arch support on Windows desktop and server has been limited to x86, x64 & Itanium.